# Batch-File Stops at first Line or Ends up in Loop

Tags: batch-file

I have a little problem I don't understand. First off I am a Rookie and never done Batch-Scripting before. I made two scripts for my company including the command nslookup

**First script:** in this script the nslookup command shall print me out the results of a specific ip range, but after "echo NSLOOKUP" nothing is displayed" The for-loop doesn't execute. But it worked last week with the same code:

```
    @echo off 
for /L %%x IN (33, 1, 60) DO (
    echo _______________________
    echo NS LOOKUP
    nslookup 192.168.178.%%x 
) 
pause
```

**Second script:** Here it's a bit different. I can enter the name for the domain, but after that it doesnt execute the nslookup-command aswell

```
@echo off

set input=y

:while
if %input%==n (
    exit
)

echo _______________
echo Name for nslookup
set /p name=

nslookup %name%.domain.domain.domain.de
echo _______________
echo Search another one? (y/n)
set /p input=
goto while
```

Also whenever I make a new batch-file and typing something like:

```
@echo off
echo tell me your name
set /p name=
echo tell me your age
set /p age=
echo %name%
echo %age%
pause
```

It just end in a loop with an input of name and age.
I am confused. Please help me. I'd appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: can't replicate any of your problems (and can't imagine a reason for any of them) I guess you don't have a programming issue but a computer issue.

Comment: Did name the first batch `nslookup.bat` ?

Comment: @LotPings I posted that exact same question to OP earlier but then deleted it because what I thought of later was the fact that he said that it worked the previous week, so unless he changed the name. Let's see what he responds with.

Comment: Was also my first thought, but if the name were `nslookup.bat`, it wouldn't just stop, but loop echoing `-----------`. Same for second script

Comment: At the top of your script, replace `@ECHO OFF` with `@ECHO ON`.  Now run the batch file from the command prompt instead of executing it with your mouse. Update your question with the output of each batch file.

Comment: I am sorry, that I didn't answer for a long time. I wasn't able to accomplish it on windows. I've moved to linux shell-scripting and it works fine now.
But thank you for your help